# jQuery data.length in 1.4.4 vs 1.5.2 (length of undefined)

Tags: jquery

In jQuery 1.4.4. I had an Ajax call, and on success I'd check if there was anything returned, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            //do something...
        }
        else {
            //do something else...
        }
    }
});
```

Even if nothing was returned, data.length would return 0 and all would work OK. Now in 1.5.2. data itself is "undefined" and of course, length of undefined is also undefined.

Any idea as to what happened in between these two versions? It's quite difficult to upgrade to a newer jQuery release when these things aren't documented well.

Comment: can you post the response of the ajax request?

Comment: I could, but you wouldn't see it - it's empty :) That's actually the problem, when the response is empty, I'm in trouble. When I have an actual response, everything works as expected.

Comment: what mime type does the response use? since you have not specified any dataType jquery uses mimetypes to interpret the ajax response

Comment: wow, you're absolutely right - adding dataType: 'html' helped. please put this as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you have not given any `dataType` jquery interprets the response using the MIME type of the response. You can give dataType explicitly to have the data interpreted as whatever you want

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            //do something...
        }
        else {
            //do something else...
        }
    }
});
```

in this case `data` will be HTML as plain text. empty response returns an empty string. length of empty string is 0 and the code works as expected.